# xspf disable Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xspf

My HTML code has a XSPF player that that autoplays:

```
<div id="mp3">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="xspf_player_slim.swf?&amp;playlist_url=play.xspf&amp;color=8A754A&amp;autoplay=true&amp;repeat_playlist=true&amp;txt_color=FF6600" width="180" height="15">
<param name="movie" value="xspf_player_slim.swf?&amp;playlist_url=play.xspf&amp;color=8A754A&amp;autoplay=true&amp;repeat_playlist=true&amp;txt_color=FF6600" /></object>
</div>
```

Now, there is a video in the same web.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh29_SERH0Y?rel=0" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Video YouTube">
```

The problem is when I play video, XSPF is playing on background, and I don't know how to disable when video is playing. Don't see options in XSPF website.

Any suggestion? any JavaScript code to stop it?

Comment: `height="15"`? this must be a L-A-N-D-S-C-A-P-E video eh?

Comment: no, it's the minimal size ;-)